# elements repeating continuously in jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I've put two links in caroufredsel to hover on and off when I hover over the carousel, but when I hover over it rapidly, the links flash on and off continuously depending on the amount of times I've entered the carousel. Is there any way to make it so that the mouseenter/leave events don't happen so rapidly?

I know the plugin comes with its own types of buttons, but it uses sprites and I don't know how to make those.

Here's the short jQuery code that I've used for this:

```
 $('#prev, #next').hide();
    $('.image_carousel').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#prev, #next').show("slow");
    });
    $('.image_carousel').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#prev, #next').hide("slow");
});`
```

and the html:

```
<div class="image_carousel">

    <div id="carousel">
        carousel items...
    </div>

    <a class="prev" id="prev" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-left icon-4x"></i></a>
    <a class="next" id="next" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right icon-4x"></i></a>
</div>
```

In Chrome DevTools it shows that the two anchor tags are getting a lot of different styles attached to them, such as opacity being set to one and decrementing, overflow: hidden, width, padding, height and margin. These are being given each time the mouse enters and leaves.

Comment: I've tried using .hover() on .image_carousel with the fadeToggle() function, but it still repeats the fade in/out if I hover over it quickly for each time I've entered .image_carousel. It is better than above, but still noticeable, and it only adds/removes opacity instead of margin, overflow, width, etc compared to fadeIn

Comment: i made a jsfiddle, not the greatest but if you hover your mouse in and out of the result box really fast you will see the black dots flashing continuously (those are my buttons :/). I want to stop that, the JS in this fiddle is my latest attempt http://jsfiddle.net/BrshS/